# method not being called java

Tags: java, android

So theres this method i want to call whenever user clicks a button. It doesnt work.
Heres the code.
What could be the issue here.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final Button refresh=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    displayer();
     refresh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
             TextView Tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TV);
             TextView Tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Tv2);
             String date = sdf.format(calendar.getTime());
             Tv.setText("The current time is " + date);
             String str = date.charAt(0) + "" + date.charAt(1) + "" + date.charAt(3) + "" + date.charAt(4);
             Tv2.setText("So the password will be " + str);
         }
     });

private void displayer() {
    TextView Tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.TV);
    TextView Tv2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.Tv2);
    String date = sdf.format(calendar.getTime());
    Tv.setText("The current time is "+date);
    String str=date.charAt(0)+""+date.charAt(1)+""+date.charAt(3)+""+date.charAt(4);
    Tv2.setText("So the password will be " + str);
}
```

<--------------------------EDIT---------------------------->
Here is the edited file. The method isnt called. As in there is no change in the textview.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final Button refresh=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    final TextView Tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.TV);
    final TextView Tv2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.Tv2);
    displayer();
     refresh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
             displayer();
         }
     });
}

private void displayer() {
    String date = sdf.format(calendar.getTime());
    Tv.setText("The current time is "+date);
    String str=date.charAt(0)+""+date.charAt(1)+""+date.charAt(3)+""+date.charAt(4);
    Tv2.setText("So the password will be " + str);
  }
```

The error showing is that in method displayer Tv and Tv2 are not found.

Comment: How did you assume that it doesn't work? What was the expected behaviour and what happened?

Comment: please be clear when you are asking question on SO.

Comment: Which method are you calling on button click ? Is it displayer() ?

Comment: Hey. The method i want to call is displayer() when the button is clicked. theres a textview which displays the time. so when the button is clicked the displayer() method will run and the textview will update. 
unfortunately the textview isnt changing

Comment: Dear, Where you have called method ? You did not called it. call as displayer(); inside your button click method.

Comment: Hey,
Sorry for the inconvenience. Actually i thought that the method was there. displayer() in the onClick.
Apologies for that.
But ive tried the way Strider has told me and it still doesnt work, the time does not get changed. the text is the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move your `displayer();` below:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
```

so you get:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
     displayer(); //Call method "displayer" when user presses button
     TextView Tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TV);
     TextView Tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Tv2);
     String date = sdf.format(calendar.getTime());
     Tv.setText("The current time is " + date);
     String str = date.charAt(0) + "" + date.charAt(1) + "" + date.charAt(3) + "" + date.charAt(4);
     Tv2.setText("So the password will be " + str);
}
```

But because there is no point in doing the same thing twice, you'll only need:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
     displayer();         //Call method "displayer" when user presses button
}
```

***Edit***
So all in all your code would look like this:

```
private Button refresh;
private TextView Tv;
private TextView Tv2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    refresh = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    Tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TV);
    Tv2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Tv2);

    refresh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        displayer();            //Call method "displayer" when user presses button
    }
});

private void displayer() {
    String date = sdf.format(calendar.getTime());
    Tv.setText("The current time is "+date);
    String str=date.charAt(0)+""+date.charAt(1)+""+date.charAt(3)+""+date.charAt(4);
    Tv2.setText("So the password will be " + str);
}
```

***PS:*** Check if your id's aren't mixed up in your XML

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/TV"   //ID is important
        //Probably more stuff
/>
```

and

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/Tv2"  //ID is important
        //Probably more stuff
/>
```

Comment: whats the point of the TextView and all below if ive already called the function which does the same exact thing.
either ways it does not work.
without method and with method

Comment: I only answered to your question why your method wasn't get called. But i'll edit my post for u. If you got any more questions, than please give us your logcat, or tell us what error(s) u get.

Comment: Hey, But it isnt working. on click the textview doesnt change at all.

Comment: check my last edit, I think that's why it aint working

Comment: Made a little mistake fixed it now, srry. Hope u got it working now ;)

Comment: Hey, It doesnt work as the final is in the onCreate. So the displayer cant find the Tv and Tv2.

Comment: and even after declaring final in the method displayer, it doesnt work

Comment: What errors do u get? and make sure all names/id's are correct!

Comment: srry the declaration should be outside `onCreate`. Try it now

Comment: it cant be out of oncreate. if it is before oncreate there will be null pointer exception

Comment: should work! but ok, use `TextView Tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TV);` and  `TextView Tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Tv2);` inside `displayer()` method (like u had it before).

Comment: If this doens't work, than u need to check your textview id's, probably the `findViewById` that can't find your textview in the layout. maybe post your layour XML.

Comment: Hey Strider. is it possible for you to discuss this on chat? like anything like facebook or anything.
i have the code and i cant put it up here just cause its a project im doing i dont want others to know. Can i have your email or something?
or just drop in a mail to me at rishabhminocha99900@gmail.com